# jPlayer and jScrollPane not working together

Tags: javascript, jscrollpane, jplayer

I'm creating a streaming music service on my website using a fork of jPlayer called jPlaylister.

One thing this doesn't do is scroll the playlist to the currently playing song.
I would also like to implement a nicer scrollbar for manually scrolling the playlist (instead of using browser default).

I came across http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/index.html which looks perfect for what i want (it can do both things).

So when i tried implementing it, it just didn't work. No results, nothing. It's like the code wasn't even there.

I of course included the neccessary js files and put the below JS function in my head:

```
$(function()
{
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
});
```

I actually changed the `.scroll-pane` class name to an existing class name (the one which i want to scroll of course).

If anyone has successfully got this working (as i've seen a few questions on the same subject on various forums, websites etc) then i'd love some help!

Answer (score 0):

The development version (http://jplaylister.yaheard.us/dev/) has this feature...I'm long overdue for a release, but prepped the files for someone else and will be happy to pass it on to you if you are interested.

nc (jplaylister author)

email at thenickchapman ... gmail or use the jplayer google group and tag me or something crazy.